# change default window manager to LXDE

Tags: window-manager, lxde, osmc

It is funny, but I cannot find out how to change the windowmanager that starts automatically to lxde.

At the moment on my Raspberry Pi it auto starts OSMC

---

edit: I have to exit that and start lxde with `startx`

---

I edited the file

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mediacenter.service
```

that launches Kodi. there I edited the line

```
ExecStart = /usr/bin/startx
```

Now lxde starts automatically, **but as root**

How do I change that the user osmc starts X?

Answer (score 1):

Run this command `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` for a graphical environment because you have used `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` before.

Answer (score -1):

Backup and delete the file. After that, install lightdm or something else. At next boot, kodi wont run and the pi shows you a fine lightdm Screen.